# How do I get coordinates programatically from Google Maps url sharing current location?

Tags: django, google-maps, django-rest-framework, geolocation, twilio-api

If I share my current location to a web server how can I get my coordinates from the shortened url?

This feature is available in the Google Maps mobile app in which users can choose to share a URL of their live location to friends via SMS.

For example, if my current url sharing location is `https://maps.app.goo.gl/***random sequence of letters***` how can I get my location?

I've set up a Django web server that communicates with a Twilio client. When I text the Twilio number with the url of my live location I want it to return my coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding)